# Multi targetting net461 and netstandard - netstandard dependencies required even in net461 consumer

Tags: c#, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0, multitargeting, multi-targeting

I'm working on a class library that I've multi-targetted to both `net461` and `netstandard2.0`

One of the dependencies of this class library is `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights`

When it was targeting *just* net461, I could add a reference to `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights` (v2.4.0) via package manager console, or nuget ui, and it would add itself as a dependency.

Once I've multi-targetted the csproj:

```
 <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net461;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

... if I try to add a reference, it asks me to accept license agreements for many, many dependencies.
Of course, I duly did so.

My issue comes when I package this class library as a nuget package.

Even if my consuming application targets `net461`, when I install this package, I am prompted to install all the netstandard dependencies - even if my consuming application doesn't target netstandard.

Is there a way to stop my `net461` targetted package requiring all the dependencies for `netstandard`?

Comment: Hey Alex, I just tried this locally cause it wasn't what I was expecting, and I get a different result. When I create a `net451` console app, and add a new mutli-targeted package (as you've defined above), I only get `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights` and `System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource` as expected, and no `NETStandard.Library`. Am I missing a step?

Comment: I would recommend looking at the contents of `obj\project.assets.json` to see what is pulling in those dependencies, cause what what you've described it will not be the app insights package.

Comment: So, this was ultimately caused by an up-stream dependency of the package not being upgraded!
I've voted to close this question.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using conditions in the project file to make some dependencies target framework specific? I've had similar sounding problems, though not with creating nuget packages, and this helped.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net461;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net461' ">
    <Reference Include="DependencyA" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0' ">
    <PackageReference Include="DependencyB" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Another idea would be to look at existing open source projects out there and see how they're solving it. Though finding one using `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights` may be trickier.

Comment: Problem is, `DependencyA` and `DependencyB` are exactly the same - including the same version